# Uploading excel file to server

Tags: php, excel, upload, ms-office

I'm unable to upload msoffice files to a folder on a server, I can upload .pdf and picture files, but not .docx, .xlsx, or even .txt, all my syntax looks correct from my limited knowledge. This is the form

```
<form id="Upload" action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="fileSelect">Navigate and choose:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="fileSelect"><br><br>
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="action" value="Upload to Shared Folder">
</form>
```

and this is the upload_file.php

```
    if(isset($_FILES["file"]["error"])){
if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else{
    $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png", "doc" => "application/msword", "docx" => "application/msword", "xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel", "xlsx" => "application/vnd.ms-excel", "pdf" => "application/pdf", "txt" => "application/txt");
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $filetype = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
    $filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];

    // siati faaopoopo
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) die("Error: This file is not an accepted file type.</br></br>");

    // siati fua - 10MB
    $maxsize = 200000 * 60;
    if($filesize > $maxsize) die("Error: File size is larger than the allowed 10MB limit.</br></br>");

    // siati MYME 
    if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)){
        // Check whether file exists before uploading it
        if(file_exists("general/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. Go back and choose another file or rename the original.</br></br>";
        } else{
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "general/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            echo "The file was uploaded successfully.</br></br>";
        } 
    } 
    else{
        echo "Error: There was a problem uploading the file - please try again."; 
    }
}
} else{
echo "Error: Invalid parameters - something is very very very wrong with this upload.";
}
```

I must be missing something but haven't figured out what. I've tried looking up the application/msword and things on stackexchange and google, but it all seems to be correct. The error I get is:

```
    Error: There was a problem uploading the file - please try again.
```

Please assist

Comment: can you do a var_dump( $filetype ) to see what is actually in there? xlsx for example could also have the mimetype application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Comment: @swidmann Willing to try, how do I do that? Add that code in somewhere?

Comment: just put var_dump( $filetype ); right under your $filetype = $_FILES["file"]["type"];. maybe you want to add a die(); under the var_dump() so it prints out the variables content and stops the script

Comment: @swidmann that mimetype change worked for the excel, so I assume that is the problem with the rest as well, please put it as an answer so I can accept it, then I'm off to find alternative mimetypes for the rest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably checking against the wrong mimetype, try to dump all the mimetypes where the file could not upload.

Here is a small overview for ms office mimetypes: [office_mime_types](http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php)

If you want to make your file check a bit better and more secure you can check it like this.

```
$allowed = array(
    "xls" => array( "application/vnd.ms-excel" ),
    "xlsx" => array(
        "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    )
);

// replace this
if ( in_array( $filetype, $allowed ) ) {}

// with this
// this checks also if mimetype of xlsx is just a mimetype of xlsx and nothing else
if ( isset( $allowed[$ext] ) && in_array( $filetype, $allowed[$ext] ) ) {}
```